# Awake app from stopped state (after Force Close)

Tags: android, alarmmanager, forceclose

I have an app in the Play Store for almost 2 years with the average rate of 4.6. The app is in reminders category and relies on AlarmManager. Unfortunately recently long time users start contacting me saying that app used to work for a long time and stopped recently. I know that the reason is the custom implementation of battery saving mechanisms by different phones' vendors. But the other reason is task killer (cleaning) apps like Clean Master that Force Close other apps.

The issue is that after Force Closing my app goes to stopped state and do not answer to any intents that are broadcasted by the system because system intents are sent with FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES flag (according to https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols).

Is there any solution to get my app out of **stopped stated** if it is put there by task killer? Or to prevent from being killed by such app?